# Windows 7: Time changes 2 hours back and when I change it goes to normal for about one day then back to 2 hours back

Tags: windows-7

I use mac and I have both operative systems. But on windows my time changes 2 hours back and when I correct it it works for like one day. This messes up things which use time. What should I do? I don't think it is because I have windows on mac but there might be something wrong with the time... Does anyone know how to fix this? When I notice I did go to Spain when about it started. Is the time zones a problem? I normally live in Norway. This is one time zone away and does that make the system go 2 hours back?

Comment: Do you have it set to the correct time zone? Have you checked your Daylight Savings Time Settings? It could be a combination of both. Also, have you tried synchronizing with a time server?

Comment: I have set it to the correct time zone yes and I'll see about the Daylight Savings Time Settings and the synchronizing.